# How to set additional values on model for Enum values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, enums, bootstrap-5, enumeration

I'm brand new to the ASP.NET MVC world.

I'm working on an MVC widget in Sitefinity. It is to create an alert on the page. Below is how the View looks. It's all built with Bootstrap 5 on the front end.

Based on the option selected from the dropdown, `alert-` will be appended with, for example, `danger` and the class `alert-danger` is what's passed to the front end. It all works great, but in the Enum, I'd like to display the values to start with a capital letter.

If I do that, then the output class becomes:

`alert-Danger`, `alert-Success`, etc.

This video provides a display of what my result is.

https://youtu.be/uNVtqMzQ8_A

[image]

**Model**

```
namespace SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Models
{
    public enum AlertStatus
    {
        primary, 
        secondary, 
        success, 
        danger, 
        warning, 
        info
    }
    public class AlertModel
    {
        public string AlertText { get; set; }
        public AlertStatus Enum { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Models.AlertModel

<div class="alert alert-@Model.Enum alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
    @Model.AlertText
    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
using SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Models;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Telerik.Sitefinity.Mvc;

namespace SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Controllers
{
    [ControllerToolboxItem(Name = "Alert", Title = "Alert", SectionName = "COS Widgets")]
    public class AlertController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Alert
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new AlertModel();
            model.AlertText = this.AlertText;
            model.Enum = this.Enum;
            return View(model);
        }
        
        protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionName)
        {
            this.ActionInvoker.InvokeAction(this.ControllerContext, "Index");
        }

        [DisplayName("Alert Text")]
        public string AlertText { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Alert Status")]
        public AlertStatus Enum { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: there are better ways to achieve what you want. assign a javascript event to the dropdown, and when this event is triggered, update the class of the text object by selecting it with its id. you can use jquery in this event.

Comment: As I am new to this area of development... why is using JS better?

Comment: creating an enum and doing string appendage etc. just to update the class of a div in front-end is really not the right way. for front-end stuff like this, you should use javascript

Comment: I'm not really understanding how to include JS in the model? Do you have a good resource for that? Search results don't really provide anything clear.

Comment: i've read your question carefully again, and it seems you want to show an error when the button is pressed. for this, you can use the validation tag helpers https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/validation-tag-helpers-in-asp-net-core-mvc/

Comment: wrap the elements in a form, submit that form, and validate with that method.

Comment: This is all my code. When I build the project, the widget is created. I didn't hold back.

Comment: Here's a screenshare video of my result. There is no button to click and there's no error I want to show. This video should explain it. [YouTube Screenshare](https://youtu.be/uNVtqMzQ8_A)

Comment: It's also worth noting that this dropdown is on the backend of Sitefinity. It's not something the frontend user sees. After the website content editor creates the alert (adds the text, selects the alert color from the dropdown), then the frontend user only sees actual alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the View, you can just use this:

`alert-@Model.Enum.ToString().ToLower()` to make it lowercase.

Comment: Thank you for the simple answer!